# how can i send a HTML email?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I've being googling already for a couple weeks and cannot find an answer for my question:

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#box1 {
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    //width:150px;
    //height:150px;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    left:10px;
    bottom:10px;
}
#box2 {
    position:absolute;
    background:green;
    top:20px;
    right:20px;
    left:20px;
    bottom:20px;
}
#box3 {
    position:absolute;
    background:blue;
    top:130px;
    right:130px;
    left:130px;
    bottom:130px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I send this in an email in order that the user just gets an email with the following result?:

> Hello World

I'm working on **Outlook 2010**

Comment: https://ucdavistechtalk.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/how-to-send-an-html-e-mail-from-outlook-2010/

Comment: Already tried @ZeRubeus but not working... and I get still bad feedback, lol

Answer (score 1):

Click 'New Email', then 'Attach File', select the file containing your HTML code, then click the arrow next to 'Insert' and select 'Insert as Text' from the dropdown. [image: Insert as Text]

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Outlook OFT email templates**

> Save your HTML file as an Outlook OFT email template, then pre-load your email with the OFT template

---

Read this [resource](https://www.outlook-apps.com/outlook-template-emails/), it will help you.

Comment: You really should try not to using css and divs in HTML emails if you want good email client compatibility- tables and inline css are your go-to's. You can use css, but more for overall responsive stylings. Both Mailchimp and CampaignMonitor have great resources on how to code for emails. Also just an FYI if you go down the OFT route (which will work for you), don't try creating responsive emails, it doesn't work well at all in that template